# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libz3java in java.library.path

Tags: java, z3

I am a beginner when it comes to z3 and java and have been trying to install it for quite some while now. I have followed all the instructions given on http://leodemoura.github.io/blog/2012/12/10/z3-for-java.html and it has been successful till it comes to the last step, that is to run -

"LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java -cp com.microsoft.z3.jar:. JavaExample" (on Linux and FreeBSD) command.

Then I get an error stating that  - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libz3java in java.library.path: [., /usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]

To solve this I googled and found out that you need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH,  I have followed the advice given on the various pages but have not been successful. Also, on the input of " env | grep '^LD_LIBRARY_PATH' " I get - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/chaitanya/z3/build, which is where my libz3java.so file is located and I believe that is what is being asked for.

Can you please tell me how to get it working ? Last time I had changed the permission of my entire 'usr' folder and pasted the libz3java.so file by changing the permissions of the entire folder and that led to a lot of problems and complications and finally led to me formatting my system with a fresh install of Ubuntu. What would be the easiest way to solve this problem and get z3 java bindings running on my system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case: on OSX it's `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For some Java versions it may be necessary to add the Z3 directory to `java.library.path` as indicated in your error message. I.e., Run `java -Djava.library.path="/path/to/directory/containing/libz3java.so" ...`

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Also, if I need to integrate z3 java bindings with eclipse, what is the easiest way to do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: Just set the same options in the project settings? Not sure what you mean by "integrate" with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods depending upon your configuration:

1. In eclipse: Run As -> Run Configurations -> Arguments Tab -> then inside VM Arguments, put this:

   -Djava.library.path=/path/to/libz3.so/and/libz3java.so/files>
2. When using cmd, run as:

   java -Djava.library.path="/path/to/directory/containing/libz3java.so" ...

Note:
For Windows: extension will be ".dll".
For Ubuntu: extension will be ".so".
For Mac: extension will be ".dylib".

Extensions for libz3 and libz3java file.